# Why do RemoteViews (Widgets) not support EditText views in Android?

Tags: android

It seems like it would be very useful to make a widget that you can type directly into.

Does anyone know what the rationale was for not supporting it, and if it's slated to be supported on future versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for EditText in app widgets is currently not planned.

Comment: you sound certain.  do you work on Android? If so, would you be so kind as to what the reasoning was behind leaving it out?

Comment: "do you work on Android?" - guess it pays to know who you are talking to :)